# Utility to create sql statements

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, utility

This is a question about Sql generation, not sql creating sql nor ORM.

Is their any cross database tools that will enable the creation of insert statements, e.g. for all the tables in particular schema or namespace. Say the namespace/schema is Aqua in Sql Server 2008, and your utility comes along and generates all possible insert statements for that namespace/schema. And it works on Oracle/MySql/Postgres/db2 etc.

Thanks.
 Bob

Comment: The INSERT statement, using either the `VALUES` or `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax is widely supported.  As long as you don't use vendor specific syntax (not much of for INSERT), you'll be fine.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, Thanks, I'm really looking for summat that will create vendor specific sql, not generic or Ansi equivs.

Comment: @scope_creep: what exactly do you mean with "all possible insert statements"? *"All possible"* is an infinite number.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, dude, how can you have an infinite number of insert statements when your schema is a finite size.

Comment: He means the database vendors

Comment: @scope_creep: so what exactly do you mean with "all possible"? For a single table there is an infinite number of possible INSERT statements. Or do you want to have one "blueprint" INSERT for each table? I still don't understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI SQL provides for a standard set of views under the schema INFORMATION_SCHEMA to provide metadata for just this purpose.

For generating simple table insert statement templates, all the information you really need to generate an insert statement for a given table is to execute this query:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG = <my-db-name>
  and TABLE_SCHEMA  = <table-owner-schema>
  and TABLE_NAME    = <table-name>
order by ORDINAL_POSITION
```

in any database that supports the ANSI information schema views. That will give you one row for every column in the specified table, in the expected sequence.

Outside of the above, since no two vendors support the set of system tables with metadata, your pretty much SOL for a cross-database solution. And sadly, I don't believe the Oracle supports the ANSI information schema views.

Though you might look at Red Gate's product family: http://www.red-gate.com/

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas, That reflects on what I have found. I thought Toad might have been able to do it. It used to, but I see it's owned by Quest now and is also now vendor specific. I'll take a look at the red-gate sql utils, see what they have.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a quick utility to create fastest possible effeciency of insert, or bulk load for a given db architecture, similar to the bulk loading of data warehouse, but a different scenario here. Instead there is loads of crud generators utilities, half a dozen code generators, like antrl, llbgen.